# Resetting Cisco Aironet 1100 to factory defaults

Tags: cisco, wifi, access-point

Can't find anything online elsewhere, bought the piece on ebay used.. It's out of warranty, Cisco won't have anything to do with telling me how. HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset the AP follow use the following steps:

- Step 1      Disconnect power from access point.
- Step 2      Press and hold MODE button while you reconnect power to the access point.
- Step 3      Hold the MODE button until the status LED turns amber, and release the button.
- Step 4      After the access point reboots, you must reconfigure the access point by using the Web-browser interface or the CLI.

The initial IP address of the AP is 10.0.0.1 with DHCP server range 10.0.0.11 and 10.0.0.30

Source : http://www.experts-exchange.com/Security/Software_Firewalls/Enterprise_Firewalls/Cisco_PIX_Firewall/Q_23739350.html